# Using Qt with custom MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, qt, g++, mingw

I don't know if this question would fit better on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), but since it's rather compiler related, I give it a try here.

I have to use Qt with a specific version of gcc (4.5). I downloaded the last official Qt release for Windows (Vista, 32 bits version) and **didn't install** the shipped MinGW version; I just installed the Qt libraries/binaries.

In a console, when I type `qmake && make`, `make` fails, complaining that `'g++' is not recognized as an internal command`.

If I type `g++` **in the same console**, I however have the following output:

```
g++: no input files
```

So `g++` is definitely recognized.

For those who may ask, both the Qt binaries directory and MinGW binaries directory are in the system `PATH` environment variable.

What could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "not an internal command" message is not one you would get if the g++ executable simply could not be found. For example, this makefile:

```
foo:
    zz foo.cpp
```

gives the error:

```
make: zz: Command not found
```

when the zz executabe does not exist. I don't know what is meant by an "internal command", but I think you need to post the part of the makefile tat causes the problem. Oh, and check that you are actually using GNU make.

Comment: Actually, I translated the error message; that's why it probably isn't accurate. Anyway, your last assumption helped me a lot: it was using some weird `make.exe` from a GNU tools package and not the legacy MinGW's `make.exe`. Thanks.

Comment: @erreOn This is one of the main reasons I don't believe programming tools should be internationalised!